# VSTO: Add controls in attachment section of a mail?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Adobe is able to put some controls in the "attachment" section of a mail...

[image]

How can I do this in VSTO?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTO doesn't provide anything for that. You may consider adding an Outlook form region, but they don't provide any layouts at the top of the window.

You need to use Windows API functions for subclassing Outlook windows if you want to get something like that. For example, see [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a).

Comment: Use Windows API functions for inserting your controls wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. The best you can do is a form region.

Comment: There is no API for that. You can find the right HWND and make your control its child - play with it with Spy++.